# MySQL gets slow before optimizing table

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization

We have a custom made webshop built on the Laravel PHP framework which processes, on a busy day, 7000 orders a day. Since all orders are sent to a third-party point of sale system via an API, the retention of the orders table is 30 days. Old orders are deleted every day.

**Table relations with volume**

[image: Table relations with volume]

**Number of orders per hour of a busy day**

[image: Number of orders per hour]

On a typical busy day like this one, there's a good chance something happens to the orders table which causes the MySQL query queue (`SHOW PROCESSLIST`) to build up and everything becomes really slow. MySQL CPU usage goes to 1400 % (it's a VPS). At these times, a couple of hundred queries are in the queue, waiting to be executed.

When I optimize the orders table (`OPTIMIZE TABLE orders`) which triggers a recreate + analyze, the queue quickly drains and within a couple of minutes, everything is back to normal.

**What is the cause of this problem and how can we prevent this?** Please let me know if there's additional information needed.

*CentOS 7.9 (Linux), MySQL 8.0.33, InnoDB, utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation*

Answer (score 0):

> the retention of the orders table is 30 days

Then I recommend `PARTITION BY RANGE(..)` to have daily partitions.  This lets you very efficiently `DROP PARTITION` at, say, midnight.  And, since it is not messing with the BTree in the way that `DELETE` does, there is no need for `OPTIMIZE`.  More: [*Partition*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)  You probably need to Partition all three tables and do a DROP on each.

Also, `REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO` tomorrow and a new, empty, `future`. as explained in the blog.  (Do this just before midnight.)

> CPU usage goes to 1400 %

This is likely to be curable by improving the `INDEXes` and/or query formulation.  Discover the slowest queries ([*SlowLog*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)) and let's work on them.

(If the high CPU usage goes away sufficiently after eliminating `OPTIMIZE`, then this step may not be needed.  However, it would be wise to watch the slowlog for further growth.)

You should probably never run `OPTIMIZE`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The provided blog says _Don't use PARTITION unless you will have >1M rows_. What are your thoughts on this? Since our table will be around 72k rows.

Comment: 1M:  It is not a strong rule.  Just a reminder that Partitioning does not help much.